# Make Dependencies that are not Monitored for Changes

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write a Make rule that says, roughly, "If you need to build **target**, also build **prereq**.  However, do *not* rebuild **target** because **prereq** changes."

Right now I am using this hack:

```
target: otherprereqs
   $(MAKE) prereq
   RECIPE
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: This makes no sense. According to your hack, Make should rebuild `target` even if `prereq` changes.

Comment: Only if **otherprereqs** change.  **prereq** changing should not prevent building **target**, but should not be enough to cause it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, I think I know what you mean. If your version of GNUMake is recent enough, you can use [order-only prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types):

```
target: otherprereqs | prereq
    RECIPE
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, I take it back.  The description in the documentation is a little confusing.  This will build prereq if needed, but might not build target.  I want something that will build prereq only when target is built.

Comment: In that case your hack is about the best you can do. (Note that instead of invoking `$(MAKE)`, you could just put in the recipe for prereq.)